# UIPickerView varying row number - iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView which will be loaded with two different data sets based on which button the user presses. One array has a count of 10 and another 6. Is it possible to fill in the same picker view with these two datas? I end up in an error when I load up with array with count of 6 when I have set the numberOfRow method to return 10. Any ways to overcome this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the UIpickerview delegates have some sort of if statement to reflect the changes

```
if(button1 pressed){
return array
}
else{ return array 2}
```

Do the same for number of rows and datasource callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of which array you are using and return the appropriate number of rows.